# Why doesn't my moving left and right code work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Paddle:
     def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left())
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right())

    def turn_left(self):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self):
        self.x = 2
```

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: Most likely you need to call `self.canvas.move` again and use the new value of `self.x` in some way.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you aren't *turning*; you're just *translating* along the x-axis. *Turning* would be a rotation to change the direction you are facing without actually moving. (Consider a car turning, which is a combination of rotation and forward motion.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method, then trying to bind the return value to the key press. You want to bind the method itself.

```
class Paddle:
     def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        # note the lack of parentheses
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
```

Now when you press the left or right arrows, you'll trigger a call to the (bound) methods.